# How to stop wildfly-10.1 loading jar dependency marshalling and river marshalling

Tags: marshalling, wildfly-10

Hi want to avoid marshalling and river marshalling jar to load from class path of wildfly, i tried with below but its not working

In War file :
**webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
     <exclusions>
        <module name="org.jboss.marshalling"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.marshalling.river"/>
     </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```